# JQuery Show/Hide multiple elements based on combined multiple data attributes and search field

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, filter, show-hide

I have some html elements like this:

```
<div class="items">
    <div class="item" data-opt1="val1" data-opt2="val2,val3">Item 1</div>
    <div class="item" data-opt1="val4" data-opt2="val2,val5">Item 2</div>
    <div class="item" data-opt1="val1" data-opt2="val3,val6">Item 3</div>
    <div class="item" data-opt1="val7" data-opt2="val3,val5">Item 4</div>
</div>
```

and 2 variables to be used as filters, one array of options and one search string like this:

**Example 1**

```
var srcString = "val";

var filters = [
    'opt1' : ['val1'],
    'opt2' : ['val2','val6']
];
```

In this example item1 and item3 should be visible, item2 and item4 not visible.

**Example 2**

```
var srcString = "value";

var filters = [
    'opt1' : ['val1'],
    'opt2' : ['val2','val6']
];
```

All items shouldn't be visible, because var srcString contain a word that are not present in any of the data attributes.

**Example 3**

```
var srcString = "val6";

var filters = [];
```

Only item3 should be visible.

**Example 4**

```
var srcString = "";

var filters = [
    'opt1' : ['val1','val7'],
    'opt2' : ['val5']
];
```

Only item4 should be visible, because item1 and item3 (even if have opt1=val1) not have val5 in opt2.

**Example 5**

```
var srcString = "";

var filters = [
    'opt1' : ['val1','val7']
];
```

items: 1,3,4 should be visible.

I was able to make all of these filters work one by one, but problems comes when I try to combinate all of them.

Code for search:

```
$(".item").each(function(){
    var item = $(this);

    if (item.data('opt1').toLowerCase().indexOf(srcVal) >= 0 
        || item.data('opt2').toLowerCase().indexOf(srcVal) >= 0){
        item.removeClass('d-none');
    }else{
        item.addClass('d-none');
    }
});
```

Code for single filter:

```
var selectedOptions = filters['opt2'];

$(".item").each(function(){
    var item = $(this);
    let _options = item.data('opt2') + '';
    _options = _options.split(",");
    let found = _options.some(r=> selectedOptions.includes(r));
    if(found==true){
        item.removeClass('d-none');
    }else{
        item.addClass('d-none');
    }
})
```

Any help is appreciate

Comment: *I was able to make all of these filters work one by one, but problems comes when I try to combinate all of them.* - please include this attempt, it will likely be easier to update your attempt than start from scratch.

Comment: You can put the content of your second each (not the each itself, the anon-func) inside the `if` of the first one.

Comment: Could you please make an example? I don't understand what you mean..
I would like the code to be adaptable even if I have to add more attributes to filter in the future.. If/else is the best approach?

Comment: @freedomn-m I understood what you mean.. but my second each loop is based on a single and static array "selectedOptions". To combinate them, I need to work with my array "filters" where opt2 index can exists or not...

Comment: According to your code, your scenario "1" should also show Item2 as you've used `.some` (aka "any") and "val2" matches "val2"

Answer (score 0):

Adapting your existing code, you can move the 2nd check inside the pass of the 1st check.

There's a few extra checks needed such as checking that `.opt2` exists and has values, but these are simple checks.

```
  $(".item").each(function() {
    var item = $(this);

    if (item.data('opt1').toLowerCase().indexOf(srcString) >= 0 ||
      item.data('opt2').toLowerCase().indexOf(srcString) >= 0) {
      item.removeClass('d-none');

      var selectedOptions = filters['opt2'];
      if (selectedOptions != null) {

        let _options = item.data('opt2') + '';
        _options = _options.split(",");
        if (_options.length > 0) {
          let found = _options.some(r => selectedOptions.includes(r));
          if (found == true) {
            item.removeClass('d-none');
          } else {
            item.addClass('d-none');
          }
        }
      }

    } else {
      item.addClass('d-none');
    }
  });
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7t26n3pj/

*note: this uses OPs code as provided so does not match their examples exactly as missing check for `opt1`*

You can remove the `if (_available_) continue` to reduce code indentation by moving the check into a separate function and return true/false for pass/not pass - this will also allow you to add new filters going forward.

```js
function applyFilter(filter) {

  $(".item").each(function() {
    var item = $(this);

    if (passesFilter(item, filter))
      item.removeClass('d-none');
    else
      item.addClass('d-none');
  })
}

function passesFilter(item, filter) {

  if (item.data('opt1').toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.srcString) < 0 &&
    item.data('opt2').toLowerCase().indexOf(filter.srcString) < 0)

    return false;

  var selectedOptions = filter.filters['opt2'];
  if (selectedOptions == null) return true;

  let _options = item.data('opt2') + '';
  _options = _options.split(",");
  if (_options.length === 0) return true;

  let found = _options.some(r => selectedOptions.includes(r));
  return found;
}

// Examples
$("button").click(function() {
  var filter = $(this).data("filter");
  console.log(filter);
  applyFilter(filter);
});
```

```css
.d-none { display:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items">
  <div class="item" data-opt1="val1" data-opt2="val2,val3">Item 1</div>
  <div class="item" data-opt1="val4" data-opt2="val2,val5">Item 2</div>
  <div class="item" data-opt1="val1" data-opt2="val3,val6">Item 3</div>
  <div class="item" data-opt1="val7" data-opt2="val3,val5">Item 4</div>
</div>

<button type='button' data-filter='{"srcString":"val","filters":{"opt1":["val1"],"opt2":["val2","val6"]}}'>
test 1
</button>
<button type='button' data-filter='{"srcString":"value","filters":{"opt1":["val1"],"opt2":["val2","val6"]}}'>
test 2
</button>
<button type='button' data-filter='{"srcString":"val6","filters":{}'>
test 3
</button>
<button type='button' data-filter='{"srcString":"","filters":{"opt1":["val1", "val7"],"opt2":["val5"]}}'>
test 4
</button>
<button type='button' data-filter='{"srcString":"","filters":{"opt1":["val1", "val7"]}}'>
test 5
</button>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but something not work as aspected. in test 1, item 2 should not be visible, because the selected value for filter opt1 was only val1, and the item2  have opt1=val4, even if opt2 match... this is like OR in sql, probably I need something like AND

Comment: As noted, it uses your original code, which also selects item2 - this is the line `_options.some(r => selectedOptions.includes(r))` which states at least one needs to match, not all.  You probably want to change `.some` for [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

Comment: Yes, I need at least one for every attribute (if selected). changing .some with .every is not the solution